# Directly modify parent props from the child in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

In a wizard in step 1, can I directly modify a parent prop, so after mounting step 2, it will have the that prop modified prop available? Or how should I do it?

Wizard component, render

```
<Wizard>
  {this.state.step1 &&
    <Step1 dataWizard={this.state.dataWizard} />
  }
  {this.state.step2 &&
    <Step2 dataWizard={this.state.dataWizard} />
  }
</Wizard>
```

Step1 component

```
class Step1 extends React.Component {

  ...

  updateData() {
    this.props.dataWizard.idCreation = 432876;
  }
```

Comment: `props` are read-only, you should not override it directly. You can have a method in your parent component that updates the state via `this.setState`. And pass that method down for your `Step1` component.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should use the state, because

> **[Props are Read-Only](https://reactjs.org/docs/components-and-props.html#props-are-read-only)**

You should use a state in the component which renders `Wizard`, and when `Step1` is finished, it alters that state, which then will be used in `Step2`.

This is called [Lifting State Up](https://reactjs.org/docs/lifting-state-up.html).

Answer (score 2):

`props`, like `state`, is read-only and should never be mutated.

You should use a callback:

```
<Step1 
  dataWizzard={this.state.dataWizzard} 
  updateData={idCreation => 
    this.setState(prevState => ({ 
      dataWizzard: {
        ...prevState.dataWizzard,
        idCreation,
      },
    }))
  } 
/>
```

Then you call the callback in `Step1`:

```
updateData() {
  this.props.updateData(432876);
}
```